# Loop through a nested Object until a certain value is found, Trees

Tags: javascript, data-structures

me and my partner have been cracking our heads at this. we have to create a tree, that obviously has "children" below it.

all we need right now, is to loop over an object to find a certain value, if that value is not in that certain object, then go into its child property and look there.

basically what I'm asking is, how can you loop over nested objects until a certain value is found?

would super appreciate the perspective of a more experienced coder on this.

```
/// this is how one parent with a child tree looks like right now, 
essentially if we presume that the child has another child in the children property, 
how would we loop into that? 
and maybe if that child also has a child, so on and so on...

Tree {
  value: 'Parent',
  children: [ Tree { value: 'Child', children: [] } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function to loop through objects:

```js
const Tree = {
  value: 'Parent',
  children: [
  {
    value: 'Child1',
    children: [
    ]
  },
  {
    value: 'Child2',
    children: [
    {
      value: 'Child2.1',
      children: [
      {
        value: 'Child2.1.1',
        children: [
        ]
      },
      {
        value: 'Child2.1.2',
        children: [
        ]
      },
      ]
    },
    ]
  },
  ]
}

function findValue(obj, value)
{
  if (obj.value == value)
    return obj;

  let ret = null;
  for(let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++)
  {
    ret = findValue(obj.children[i], value);
    if (ret)
      break;
  }
  return ret;
}

console.log("Child1", findValue(Tree, "Child1"));
console.log("Child2.1", findValue(Tree, "Child2.1"));
console.log("Child3", findValue(Tree, "Child3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple solution:

```js
const myTree = {
    value: 'Parent',
    children: [
        {
            value: 'Child1',
            children: []
        },
        {
            value: 'Child2'
        }
    ]
}

const isValueInTree = (tree, findValue) => {
    if (tree.value === findValue) return true;

    if (tree.children && tree.children.length !== 0) {
        for (const branch of tree.children) {
            const valuePresents = isValueInTree(branch, findValue);
            if (valuePresents) return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

console.log(isValueInTree(myTree, 'Child2'));
console.log(isValueInTree(myTree, 'Child'));
console.log(isValueInTree(myTree, 'Child1'));
```